# @font-face or path issue

Tags: css, font-face

I've got a problem with my @font-face declaration. It works fine for the root folder, but isn't working for html files in subfolders.
In the root I'm calling my css file with

```
<link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and in the subfolders with

```
<link href="../css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

which is working fine, as the other css declarations are working in the subfolder. But my @font-face declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sofia';
    src: url('fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.svg#sofia') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

is only working in the root. Folder structure is like this

```
index.html
css
  fonts.css
  fonts
    sofiaporlight-webfont.eot
de
  second.html
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you check web inspector for css files are initilized or not ?

Comment: as I have written, the css file is loaded, as other css declarations are working, only the @font-face isn't doing anything in sub.

Comment: all the browsers have same result ?

Comment: hah, it looks like it's a firefox problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" to false in the about:config
settings

[Firefox Security Policy](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy)

"Local documents have access to other local documents in the same directory and in subdirectories, but not directory listings. (Default) "

[Orginal Answer](http://fontsquirrel.com/forum/discussion/196/cant-use-fontface-with-relative-path-locallyfirefox-only/p1)

This can cause the error,try to change firefox config as mentioned, if you are working on remote host, you need edit htaccess

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems here you can find the information

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one, because your font/s are in fonts folder and that folder is in css folder. So provide full path and try.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'sofia';
src: url('css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot');
src: url('css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.svg#sofia') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: with this code, it's not working in root and subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Just try /css/fonts/...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sofia';
    src: url('/css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.svg#sofia') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: same result. But it looks like it's a Firefox related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sofia';
    src: url('/css/fonts/sofiaprolight-webfont.eot');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```